# Understanding SQL code in a controller in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am new to ruby on rails and was going to some of the code already existing in the application.

The code is as follows(books):-

```
def index
        @books = Book
        @books = @books.select("books.*, 
                                (select count(*) from book_issues where books.id = book_issues.book_id and book_issues.return_date is null) as issued_cnt,
                                (select count(*) from book_holds where books.id = book_holds.book_id) as hold_cnt")
         @books = @books.joins("inner join book_issues on book_issues.book_id = books.id")
         @books = @books.where('book_issues.return_date is null')
         @books = @books.group('books.id')
        @books.all

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # index.html.erb
            format.json { render json: @books }
        end
    end
```

I am finding this a little difficult to understand.Why is this code being used and why not use the below code:-

```
def index
  if params[:book_id]
    @book = Book.find(:all,
                        :conditions => ["book_id = ? ", params[:book_id] ],
                        :order      => "action_date ASC")    
  end
end
```

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: The second block is totally different, it should be used for a `show` action instead of a `index`..

Comment: That controller action doesn't make sense. What do you intend to do?

Comment: @kiddorails I am actually not aware.But the code seems to work for index.It is showing all the list of books present in the database.

Comment: Looks like the index action is trying to return a grouped count of the books that are currently issued and books that are in hold when requested for json format. We should probably look at the index view to see what they are doing if html is requested

Comment: @Tim In index we are showing the values in this case books in the database.so what is the difference .Just asking

Comment: @Tim Yes. And even that seems unconventional. `book_id` in a `Book` model? `Book.where('book_id = ?', params[:book_id]).order('action_date')` will be better, even if that's the case.

Comment: use the console to see the sql query who is generating each one and see difference

Comment: @Tim Book.where('book_id = ?', params[:book_id]).order('action_date') can be used for index.

Comment: Not to be too presumptuous but that SQL code is a huge red flag.  First off it should mostly be in the book model rather than the book controller, and second there are ActiveRecord querying methods to handle most of this in a more idiomatic fashion.  You might be better off reimplementing this piece just to get a feel for how it could work.

Comment: @kiddorails True, this code doesn't make sense at all, as Daniel suggests, find out what is happening, and rewrite it, learn about assocciation, scopes, and build-in methods to find the records you want..

Comment: @DanielJ.Pritchett Any suggestions you can give me regarding the above.Am a bit confused

Comment: @peevee sure thing, I just wrote up an explanation of how I'd structure it in my own code.

Answer (score 3):

Read manuals and tutorials about associations and scoping in rails.
After that you should rewrite the code to something like this:

```
#model

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Association for BookIssue, the BookIssue model should have a 'belongs_to :book'
  has_one :book_issue
  # Association for BookHold, the BookHold model should have a 'belongs_to :book'
  has_one :book_hold
  # Scope to get not returned books, it joins all issues that don't have a return date.
  # All book with a return date will be ignored.
  scope :not_returned, joins(:book_issue).where(:book_issues => { return_date: nil } )

end

#controller

def index
  # Use the scope mentioned in the model, to get all not returned books.
  @books = Book.not_returned.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @books }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The primary problem being solved here is "generate an array of books which aren't currently checked out and pass it to the template engine to render on the page".  That SQL code is handling the first part.  It's unfortunate that you have to join against book_issues to see if there are any available copies, but disregarding that for right now you'd want to define a method on Book like `:available?` that returned true when there's at least one copy not checked out and then use that in your controller.

As a further adjustment, I'd like to have a database column on the book records that let me know if they were available for checkout **without joining against the `book_issues` table** (BooksController#Index sounds like it'd be invoked an awful lot, and you don't want it to thrash the database).  That'd mean updating your book checkout logic to tweak the master book record, maybe.

The code would be much happier if it looked like this:

```
#books controller
def index
  @books = Book.available

  respond_to ... # continue as before
end

# book model
scope :available, where(copies_available: true)

# book_issue model
belongs_to :book
after_save :update_parent_availability

def available?
  return_date.nil?
end

def update_parent_availability
  book.copies_available = book.issues.select(&:available?).any?
  book.save if book.changed?
end
```

That `:update_parent_availability` action might be subject to race conditions.  You should probably factor it out into a helper book availability management class and run it in a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find the ActiveRecord sections of the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) very helpful. I'd suggest giving the [ActiveRecord querying](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) docs a thorough read. Pay close attention to the general style of the examples. One of the most powerful aspects of the MVC (Model-View-Controller) pattern is that you can build very simple interfaces within your model that do the "heavy lifting" rather than cluttering up your controllers with logic that really doesn't belong there.